# Camel response from bean back onto ActiveMQ queue

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using Camel (with the camel-ejb dependency) to route messages from an ActiveMQ to my bean's method.  So far I've got it receiving the message in my requestHandler bean.

```
<amq:connectionFactory id="amqConnectionFactory"
    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
    id="connectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" id="jmsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>

<camel:camelContext id="camelContext">
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="activemq:queue:inQueue" />
        <camel:setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
        <camel:to uri="bean:requestHandler?method=handleRequest" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

If I now change handleRequest to return a String, how would I modify my route to put the String on the queue back to the person sending me a message?

Thanks!

EDIT:

### Client code:

(in camel-context.xml)

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:template id="camelTemplate" />
</camel:camelContext>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>
```

(in CamelClient.java)

```
public class CamelClient  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-context.xml");
        ProducerTemplate pTemplate = context.getBean("camelTemplate", ProducerTemplate.class);

        System.out.println("Message Sending started");
        String ret = pTemplate.requestBody("activemq:queue:inQueue", "47264", String.class);
        System.out.println("Message received:" + ret);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And try adding a log step in the route

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="activemq:queue:inQueue" />
    <camel:setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
    <camel:to uri="bean:requestHandler?method=handleRequest" />
    <camel:to uri="log:reply" />
</camel:route>
```

And also show us the code for your requestHandler bean what it does, can let us help you better.

Comment: Nothing logged :<  My requestHandler does a whole bunch of application code and then returns a String.  It's equivalent to your example.  I've added all the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: [reply] (Camel (camelContext) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[inQueue]) Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: String, Body: ]

Comment: public String handleRequest(String authKey) { 
...  return responseXml;
  
 }

Comment: FYI: The JMSQueueProducer was just my original testing method, which allows me to call ctx.getBean("queueProducer") and then queueProducer.send(xmlCommand);   The thing is now I've finished testing my app locally, and want to call it from another computer.

Comment: Try without all your custom code, and just return a fixed string in the method, to get all that working. Also make sure the message you receive on inQueue has a JMSReplyTo header set. If not then its in-only messaging.

Comment: ah wow, ok, I got a response this time.  Bizarre.  I guess I'll put code back in slowly, and see what is breaking it.  It doesn't make any sense.  Brb.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  String s = "";  xml = convertBlah(s); return s;  Thanks Claus.

Answer (score 2):

This happens out of the box. If the JMS message has a JMSReplyTo header then Camel sends back a reply message, when the routing is complete. So in your bean, just return what you want to send back.

So if you method is

```
public String handleRequest(String input) {
   return "Hello " + input;
}
```

Then you will send back a String with hello < original body here >

I suggest to spend a bit time reading this page

- http://camel.apache.org/jms

as JMS and camel-jms has many options, so take a bit time to learn more about it.

Comment: Hi Claus, thanks... So I've modded my camel route (question edited as per your suggestion), and I made a simple test app.  It sends a String, and my EJB receives and processes, and returns the String.  But I am not sure how to get the response back to my test app.  I call producer.send() successfully... but I don't see how I can make a consumer.receive() associate itself with the reply queue?

Comment: what producer.send() are you using ProducerTemplate, then read the javadoc of its API to know why!

Comment: I am using the client code here:  http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html  (MessageProducer, not ProducerTemplate)

Comment: Ah doing request/reply using pure JMS API requires more work. You can try using the requester - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/QueueRequestor.html

Comment: So I've tried using Camel ProducerTemplate instead, (see new client code above), and get the same result.  My bean receives the String, "47264", returns a String, but a blank string is received by the client.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: <version.camel>2.12.2</version.camel>

Answer (score 1):

You must force the exchange pattern to be inout: jms:MyQueue?exchangePattern=InOut

More info on the camel docs: http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html

Comment: Thanks, I've added <camel:setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/> but am still having trouble.  My bean seems to return a blank string to the temporary receiver queue.  I made a new issue for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457431/apache-camel-basic-request-reply